# Dash streaming on Nginx Plus

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I have hls working on nginx plus, as per this gist: https://gist.github.com/45sound/0ed2d8f971314facf72c

I assumed I could add a new location like this:

location /dash{
  dash;
  root /var/www
}

but I get nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "dash" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:21 when I restart server.

Ideally I want to serve hls and dash content from same server.
Best,
Vinny
FanFootage.com

Edit:   http://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.ie/2013/11/mpeg-dash-live-streaming-in-nginx-rtmp.html is the example i followed, and both "dash" and "dash on" gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx Plus [supports](https://www.nginx.com/products/streaming-media-delivery/) `Apple HLS` and `Adobe HDS` for video-on-demand (VOD) only. There is no mention of a `DASH` module.

You can always `DASH` yourself the files for VOD (eg: with the [GPAC MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/dash/)) and just serve the segments and manifests from any location block directly without a module.

The [Nginx RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) offers support for `MPEG-DASH` live streaming. It also works with the basic version:

```
rtmp {         
    server {

        [...]           

        application dash {
             live on;
             dash on;
             dash_path /tmp/dash;
        }
    }
}

http {
    server {
         listen      8080;

         [...]

         location /dash {
             root /tmp;
             add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to rebuild nginx with the linked RTMP module. If it's not installed you get the missing directive error

Comment: See the Build section in the Readme or use the binary from the other answer

Answer (score 0):

The NGINX RTMP Module (supports DASH) is available with NGINX Plus. It can be found in the [NGINX Plus Extras Package](https://www.nginx.com/products/technical-specs/).

Comment: It's also available on basic but you must build it

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's available on GitHub. https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module. The author of the module now works at NGINX.